# Excel Pivot Table Date Range as Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, pivot-table

I have the following data which I wish to pivot:

```
Student    JoinDate    ReleaseDate
John       01/05/2011  05/05/2011
James      02/05/2011  04/05/2011
```

I would like to create a pivot table which shows me a count of students within a given date range:

```
01/05/2011  02/05/2011  03/05/2011  04/05/2011  05/05/2011
1           2           2           2           1
```

Now, the issue I have is that I want the pivot table to somehow expand out the dates, I can't figure out how to achieve this with my current data structure.

I can achieve it with the following structure:

```
Student    JoinDate    ReleaseDate   PivotDate
John       01/05/2011  05/05/2011    01/05/2011
John       01/05/2011  05/05/2011    02/05/2011
John       01/05/2011  05/05/2011    03/05/2011
John       01/05/2011  05/05/2011    04/05/2011
John       01/05/2011  05/05/2011    05/05/2011
James      02/05/2011  04/05/2011    02/05/2011
James      02/05/2011  04/05/2011    03/05/2011
etc...
```

But this technique doesn't scale very well given the amount of data in use, I'm easily hitting the maximum number of rows for a single sheet in the workbook.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can create the desired pivot table without having a row for each date the student is 'active'..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to try a solution that doesn't involve pivot tables:

Remove the Pivot Date column. Arrange the date range in headers and use the **AND()** formula to determine if that date falls within the student's tenure. Your data will look something like this:

[image]

Here's how the formula in **D2** looks like (note the absolute references). Just drag or copy the formula to the rest of the columns and rows, autofill should take care of the rest:

```
=AND(D$1>=$B2,D$1<=$C2)+0
```

Number format is set to this: `"+";;`

The formula for the total number of students per date range is pretty easy. Here's the formula for **D26** above.

```
=sum(D2:D25)
```

To add columns, just copy the last column and change the date above. To add students, insert a blank row above the last student (in this case, above *Banshee*). Record a macro to make it easier for you to update the data. This way you don't have to manually adjust the **SUM** formula at the bottom row. You can sort the data by Student name, Join date or Release date; the formulas at the right should be fine.

Here's a copy of the spreadsheet shown above (requires MS Excel 2007): http://ge.tt/46auqAN

Comment: This is great. It would be wonderful to provide a sample formula in the text of the answer, not just in a download sample, in case that is later not available.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that ge.tt links expire after 30 days. I updated the post to include the formulas. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can get these counts with an array formula.  No need for Pivot at all.

Assuming JoinDate is in `column B`, ReleaseDate in `column C`, and just the two rows of data for this example.
Dates to sum against are in `columns E` onward: Formula in `E2`.  Enter as an array formula (Press **Ctrl-Shift-Enter** rather than just Enter to complete the formula)

```
=SUM(((($B$2:$B$4<=E$1)*1+($C$2:$C$4>=E$1)*1)=2)*1)
```

Copy across row 2 for each date you want a total for

The formula looks better and is easier to maintain if you use Named Ranges for the Date data

```
=SUM((((JoinDate<=E$1)*1+(ReleaseDate>=E$1)*1)=2)*1)
```

Date ranges can extend beyond the existing data to allow for adding more latter.  eg `$B$1:$B$100`
Whole column (`$B:$B`) works too, but will slow down the recalculation

By the way, if you were using **Excel 2007** or latter a new function is available (enter as regular formula, no need for array):

```
=COUNTIFS(JoinDate,"<="&E$1,ReleaseDate,">="&E$1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not suit your application, but you should try the Pivot function in MS Access this far superior to Excel